# Is this definition correct for the inverse of a function?

Tags: functions, definition, inverse

Is this definition correct for the inverse of a function?

> Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function. The **inverse** of $f$ is the function $g:Y\to X$ such that $g\circ f=i_X$ and $f\circ g=i_Y$. We denote the inverse of $f$ by $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Replace $f^{-1}$ with $g$ and it's correct.

Comment: I'd also define it as "a function," since it requires proof to prove that, when it exists, it is unique.

Comment: @GitGud: Why should I replace it?

Comment: Because you never said what $g$ is, @sisabe. The letter is just suddenly there without any meaning or context.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry, I edited my question. Is that correct now? if not, what is the correct definition?

Comment: Technically, it is bad to assert things in a definition which actually require proof. "An inverse of $f$ is a function $g$ such that ..." Would avoid asserting the uniqueness of the inverse. "The inverse" is an assertion of uniqueness, a fact which requires proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formulation of the definition in the OP assumes existence and uniqueness of the inverse, and existence is not there always while uniqueness has to proved. I would reformulate it as:

> Let $\,f:X\to Y\,$ be a function. The function $\,g:Y\to X\,$ is said to be an *inverse* of $\,f$ if $\,g\circ f=i_X\,$ and $\,f\circ g=i_Y$. We denote the inverse of $\,f\,$ by $\,f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

We only define $f^{-1}$ if $f$ is bijective. Also, as it is written, it doesn't make much sense - what is $g$? (unless you're implying that $g = f^{-1}$)

Other than this, that's pretty much it.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. Is that correct now? if not, what is the correct definition?

Comment: This is okay. Bear in mind that $f^{-1}$ will only exist if $f$ is bijective, though.